# IJCADでプログラムからプロファイルを切り替える方法について

Tags: ijcad

現在、IJCAD 2022で.NET API(C#)を使用して開発を行っています。

プログラムからプロファイルを切り替える方法を探しているのですが、方法が見つかりません。ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UserConfigurationManager.SetCurrentProfile(string name)メソッドを用いることで、プログラムからプロファイルを切り替えることが可能です。

情報は以下のURLに置かれているIJCAD開発者ヘルプの.NET APIリファレンスで、以下の方法で検索して取得しました。

https://support.ijcad.jp/hc/ja/articles/4416529488281

①上記のURLを開き、「IJCAD_2022_DEV_CHM.zip」をダウンロードする
②「IJNETDEV.chm」を開き、[検索]タブでワイルドカードを使用し「*profile*」と検索する
③UserConfigurationManager クラスの SetCurrentProfile(string name) メソッドで、指定したプロファイルを現在に設定することができることが分かる